# Alternative event when pressing the scan button on a datalogic memor device using C#

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner, keyevent

I'm using C# 2003 for a Datalogic Memor application. I have researched that a KeyPress Event is triggered when the "scan button" of the device is pressed. Capturing it was `if(e.KeyChar == 13)` but it doesn't work. Is there another alternative for this?

Comment: What are you asking? Who told you to check for `e.KeyChar == 13`? What happens if you check for other values of `e.KeyChar`? Do you get a `KeyPress` event raised *at all*?

Comment: Its a keypress, key up, key down event that is triggered because it involves pressing the "scan button/key" of the device.

Comment: Yes. All of those events will get raised. KeyDown comes first, then KeyPress, then KeyUp. You only need to process one of them, though, or you'll do the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install Datalogic SDK 2_0_0_0 
You can Download it from [Datalogic](http://www.datalogic.com/Download?path=%2fupload%2fres%2fsw%2fadc%2fdevelopment%2fnextgen%2fDatalogic_SDK_2.0.0.0.zip&iddwnfile=18496&name=Datalogic_SDK_2.0.0.0)  website.

And then add a reference to the datalogic API :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Datalogic.API.dll
```

Now you can Use the API in this way:

On your Form declaration:

```
private DecodeEvent dcdEvent;
private DecodeHandle hDcd;
```

On your form loading event:

```
// Attempt to load a handle to the decoder.

try
{
    hDcd = new DecodeHandle(DecodeDeviceCap.Exists | DecodeDeviceCap.Barcode);
}
catch(DecodeException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception loading barcode decoder.", "Decoder Error");
    return;
}

// Now that we've got a connection to a barcode reading device, assign a
// method for the DcdEvent.  A recurring request is used so that we will
// continue to get barcode data until our dialog is closed.
DecodeRequest reqType = (DecodeRequest)1 | DecodeRequest.PostRecurring;

// Initialize all events possible
//dcdEvent = new DecodeEvent(hDcd, reqType);
dcdEvent = new DecodeEvent(hDcd, reqType, this);
dcdEvent.Scanned += new DecodeScanned(dcdEvent_Scanned);
```

And this is your event listener:

```
private void dcdEvent_Scanned(object sender, DecodeEventArgs e)
{
    CodeId cID = CodeId.NoData;
    string dcdData = string.Empty;
    // Obtain the string and code id.
    try
    {
        dcdData = hDcd.ReadString(e.RequestID, ref cID);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error reading string!");
        return;
    }

    string result = "Barcode Text: " + dcdData;
    result +=" AND Barcode Code Id : " + cID.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

ON your form closing event:

```
if(dcdEvent.IsListening)
{
    dcdEvent.StopScanListener();
}

if (hDcd != null)
{
    hDcd.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Datalogic Memor X3 I use the DLScannerListener like this:

```
DLScanner Scanner = new DLScanner();
Scanner.init();
Scanner.scanEnable();
Scanner.Listeners += new DLScannerListener(scanner_notify);
```

Then I do the logic inside the method `scanner_notify`

```
private void scanner_notify(DLScannerEvent scannerEvent, DLScanner sender)
{
    //Write your code here
}
```